# Glassfish v3 problem with DB2 libs

Tags: database, jdbc, glassfish-3

I downloaded Liferay 6 bundle with glassfish v3, and Installed it, it works just fine, the only problem is adding a connection pool for DB2, I did the following steps:

1. added DB2 Libs to \domains\mydomain\lib
2. restarted Glassfish
3. Add a new Connection pool

   I. Resource Type is ConnectionPoolDataSource

   II. Class Name COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource.

when I ping, I got "Ping failed Exception - Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource. Please check the server.log for more details."

I restarted glassfish many times, added the libs to \lib
I can't figure out what the problem is, and help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I turns out I should add DB2 Library to domains\domain1\ext directory.